# How to test the passing of arguments in Golang?

Tags: testing, go, command-line-arguments

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    passArguments()
}

func passArguments() string {
    username := flag.String("user", "root", "Username for this server")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Printf("Your username is %q.", *username)

    usernameToString := *username
    return usernameToString
}
```

Passing an argument to the compiled code:

`./args -user=bla`

results in:

`Your username is "bla"`

the username that has been passed is displayed.

---

**Aim:** in order to prevent that the code needs to be build and run manually every time to test the code the aim is to write a test that is able to test the passing of arguments.

---

**Attempt**

Running the following test:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func TestArgs(t *testing.T) {
    expected := "bla"
    os.Args = []string{"-user=bla"}

    actual := passArguments()

    if actual != expected {
        t.Errorf("Test failed, expected: '%s', got:  '%s'", expected, actual)
    }
}
```

results in:

```
Your username is "root".Your username is "root".--- FAIL: TestArgs (0.00s)
    args_test.go:15: Test failed, expected: 'bla', got:  'root'
FAIL
coverage: 87.5% of statements
FAIL    tool    0.008s
```

**Problem**

It looks like that the `os.Args = []string{"-user=bla` is not able to pass this argument to the function as the outcome is `root` instead of `bla`

Comment: Have you tried `os.Args = []string{"cmd", "-user=bla"}`? Remember the very first value in `os.Args` is a (path to) executable itself.

Comment: @tomasz This works. Thank you. `args_test.go:16: Test failed, expected: 'bla', got:  'bla2'`

Comment: @tomasz Could you post your comment as an answer as it answers the question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Per my comment, the very first value in `os.Args` is a (path to) executable itself, so `os.Args = []string{"cmd", "-user=bla"}` should fix your issue. You can take a look at [flag test](https://golang.org/src/flag/flag_test.go#L318) from the standard package where they're doing something similar.

Also, as `os.Args` is a "global variable", it might be a good idea to keep the state from before the test and restore it after. Similarly to the linked test:

```
oldArgs := os.Args
defer func() { os.Args = oldArgs }()
```

This might be useful where other tests are, for example, examining the real arguments passed when evoking `go test`.

Answer (score 0):

This is old enough but still searched out, while it seems out dated.
Because [Go 1.13 changed sth.](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31859)

I find [this change](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/pull/6388/files/8a97102ebeb23f0cd088a3bf21fe315a2b83960e) helpful, putting `flag.*()` in init() and `flag.Parse()` in Test*()

-args cannot take `-<test-args>=<val>` after it, but only `<test-args>`, otherwise the test-args will be taken as go test's command line parameter, instead of your Test*'s