# Is it possible to change the value of os.Args so I can add tests to the CLI that I'm creating?

Tags: go, testing

Is it possible to change the value of `os.Args` globally in a Golang program? I'm writting a library like Cobra just for fun, and internally I make use of `os.Args` to parse the command-line arguments. I would like to do that to properly test the parser.

Currently what I am doing is manually changing the internal variable of my package, but that's a bad practice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to the previous question [How to test the passing of arguments in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723300/how-to-test-the-passing-of-arguments-in-golang) describes how to modify the os.Args during testing.

[tomasz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847869/tomasz) states " the very first value in os.Args is a (path to) executable itself, so os.Args = []string{"cmd", "-user=bla"} should fix your issue. You can take a look at [flag test](https://golang.org/src/flag/flag_test.go#L318) from the standard package where they're doing something similar."